# Help pages example workflow: Getting from a bad question to good question of the same topic

Tags: discussion, feature-request, new-users

I have been thinking about the help pages.
In the past I have often criticised that they are too vague and are open to interpretation, especially at the corner cases or for new programmers.

Often you can take off-topic or discussion questions and turn them into on-topic ones, by putting more effort into them or actually trying something practical and running into a concrete problem.

I think this is where the help pages fail. They tell you what you are allowed to do and what you are not allowed to do, but they don't provide a single example. And more importantly, they don't provide a workflow/example how you might get from a bad question/off-topic question to something that actually might be on-topic and helps the user asking the question and the site.

I think if we provided an example workflow of how to use SO,
especially if you're new,
we could save ourselves a lot of hassle and hate on both sides.

This could simply be a page with a bad question, which is refactored by the author with some additional text implying the thought process and the effort done by the example author (potentially with some example answers illustrating why questions of this kind are not allowed).

You could even make it more elaborate illustrating an author going about finding an answer for his question by trying different searches beforehand.

While all this sounds trivial and most will answer this suggestion with "if they can't come up with that themselves they shouldn't be programmers >:("

Currently the help pages are more like a bunch of guidelines, for a forum that's not a real forum. Additionally many things leave room for interpretation, which can be confusing to new authors who don't know what they got wrong, getting pointed to a vague collection of guidelines, often without mention of which of these guidelines they breached.

Additionally we have very strict rules, content criteria and banning criteria. For many people maybe coming from forum culture this can be confusing and new. Getting downvoted and closed within minutes isn't just frustrating for the people "annoyed" by the bad question but especially for the author.

Often for programmers an example of A/B right/wrong in a particular example context can be much more enlightening than abstract guidelines.

If this idea is welcome I could come up with an example of how this could look like and would edit it into here as an image link.

EDIT:
I propose showing a transformation process/workflow for taking a bad offtopic question to transform it with some work into an ontopic question.

A simple list of good and bad questions is useless, because the difference is only apparent when you see an A/A* comparisons of the same question in good and bad version.

An abstract list of rules doesn't become better by adding examples, because it does not help an OP in a certain situation, who has to improve his particular question and wants to learn about a particular topic.

That is the problem with the "just look at good questions and adapt" approach.

Comment: Part of the problem is that new users don't appear to bother looking at other recent, well-received questions before asking. This whole site's full of examples, neatly sorted into good and bad by their scores!

Comment: I think that is exactly the problem. Just by looking at something you can come to wrong conclusion and it doesn't really help you get there. You can read a book, but you don't automatically become a good author.

Comment: We can't really teach someone how to be a good author, either.  But it's a lot easier to look at a well-formatted and liked question and compare it to your awful code splat and get some hints as to what to improve.