# User consciously ignores the rules of asking questions on SO. What should I do about it?

Tags: discussion, flags, moderation

A user highlighted the following in [their question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42884580/looking-for-forex-buy-sell-demand-api):

> I ask this question on quora, answer.yahoo.com and on money.stackexchange.com but didn't find any answer, if this is not a right place to ask this question, so please don't give me down vote until i found my answer. I am asking here may be anyone work on these kind of API

In other words, the rules don't apply to me, since I can't find my answer anywhere else.

I commented about what can be asked about SO, and in reply he instructed me: *Please Read my first 3 lines. If you want to give me down vote, Please wait 24 Hours. so i will get my answer in 24 hours*

I don't appreciate this type of questions -  I don't believe that any user is above the rules, so I flagged it for a moderator, but they rejected my flag. I though it was the right thing to do - Not because "*Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster.*" but the fact that this user **ignore the rules** and also instructing not to do anything with this question, and the fact that [their question on money.stackexchange.com](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/77514/how-to-know-before-forex-currency-value-goes-up-down-i-will-develop-software) was already closed by a moderator.

So should I alert a moderator when I see users that are knowingly ignore SO rules about asking questions or just use the regular flags?

Comment: Just downvote and closevote and move on, they'll get Q-banned soon enough.

Comment: ............and deleted

Comment: Oh, and for _reasons of moderation_ no less. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the (now deleted) question, if anybody is interested: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8q7f.png

Comment: Meta messages (don't downvote, don't close, do upvote, answer me urgently) can all be removed by editing. They are common enough that I have bookmarks for all of them. I wouldn't bother a moderator for this, the OP will learn soon enough. Downvote also if you think it is egregious.

Comment: Yes @halfer I now agree with what you say that bothering a moderator is unnecessary for that type of low-quality questions. Next time I'll use the good ol' flags without involving a moderator

Comment: Great. Yes, if it can reasonably be closed as off-topic (rather than just being downvoteable) then by all means cast a close vote.

Comment: Whenever this kind of blatantly off-topic question is asked, it will often get quickly swarmed by down-votes by queue reviewers.  It will get to -5 or -6 within minutes.  I agree with the comment that the question will be auto-closed and deleted soon enough.   Almost as fast as if a moderator were called attention to it.  But lol, it did get 1 up-vote, if you look closely at the screenshot @user000001 helpfully posted..

Comment: The title is an overblown hyperbell. The user is just asking for help and kind treatment. Not everyone knows that asking for kindness is a rule violation ... .

Comment: Why you just listen to the blah blah blah by the OP. If the question not come under the rules, Take further actions.

Comment: @SagarV Then they should not post blah blah blah next time. I don't like blah blah blah.

Comment: that's what I said. _Take further actions_ . Flag it , downvote, cast a close vote. You don't have to obey the OP

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful I do agree that asking for kindness is not a rule violation, but if you take a look at the screenshot of the deleted question you'll see that the whole essence is of-topic. I posted a comment notifying them about the off-topic question with [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - If they were to edit their question and make it on-topic than they might even have an answer. But they decide not to read the rules listed in the help center.

Comment: @SagarV I know it now (As I accepted the answer suggesting similar actions as you did) so next time that's what i'll do :)

Comment: @AlonEitan, well, it's easy to transform any question asking directly for outside resources to a "how can I do x?" question + some code. The OP might have not been aware of that or able to do it, because the mindset of "I have a question that is offtopic, how do I ask/create an ontopic version after doing the necessary work?" is something you aquire on SO and isn't common outside SO. The Help pages on that are lackluster and I even proposed a change once https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336618/help-pages-examples.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful I think your suggestion is brilliant and I believe that including examples of bad (and good) questions and also description of what made those question good or bad will be much more helpful than the current docs. It might even make them more interesting to read

Comment: *"Just give me answerz b4 it gets deleted"* is the caliber of that type of asker - they totally know they're going to get deleted and they don't care, they just hope they get one person answering them before then.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

> "Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster."

This is a standard rejection text that is used when somebody uses a moderator only flag, for something that can be handled by the community alone, without any diamond moderator involvement.

In this case, if a user is ignoring the asking rules, the community can handle the situation alone. They can:

- Edit the question to remove noise
- Close the question to prevent answers
- Downvote/delete the question, so that the automated banning algorithm takes effect.

So no moderator involvement was necessary at that point.

Comment: So you're saying that I could safely remove this part of the question (the highlighted introduction on their question) and it's fine? I wasn't sure about that and thought it could start an editing war - That's also why I didn't continue to comment and let the community/moderator to decide about that

Comment: @AlonEitan: In my opinion a single edit would be appropriate. If an edit war happened, then a moderator could get involved to lock the post.

Comment: Thanks for clarify this

Comment: @AlonEitan If there's a single occurrence, then certainly it would not be useful to flag for moderator attention. If there's a repeated occurrence, the system will already have banned them. However, if we feel that a user has added a lot of bad questions (say 5 or more), then we send a message asking them to read the help pages. (not sure if a mod flag is warranted in that case, where they've asked a lot of bad questions. But if it is flagged, then I'd certainly send the user a message).

Comment: @BhargavRao Thank you. I understand from this answer that flagging it for a moderator was wrong, and I also want to make clear that the purpose of my question wasn't about moderator-shaming due to declined flag, but to better understand what I need to do next time I come across that type of questions.

Comment: @AlonEitan, It's already completely clear from your post that you want to learn. :-)

Comment: Usually it's not worth editing those. "Don't polish junk."

Comment: @AlonEitan "Noise" like that in an intrinsically bad post is actually helpful - it makes it easier to spot just how bad the question is. ;)

Comment: @JanDvorak: I take the view that if the user might stick around, a basic editing even on junk is the best way to demonstrate what was bad about the post. Of course, if it is so bad it will be deleted, then I won't bother, but there's plenty of non-deleted junk out there `:-)`.

Answer (score -60):

The guy is looking for some help. I have posted questions on this site and I feel they are good. I get downvoted to the point of not being able to post. We are here to help each other I believe.

I was working on a project a few months ago I got stuck and I asked for help on here. I received replies that did not help. I spent a few weeks trying to solve it to no avail. Now I have a project just sitting there.

I suspect most do not like to be in that situation. A lot of people on this site are just downvote trigger happy I suspect. If there was an explanation for a downvote that is understandable, there never is, though.  I have read through the rules countless times and I would still get down voted.

The behavior on this site demotivates me from using it and I am sure it does the same for others.

You are assuming he thinks the rules do not apply to him. It appears he needs help. He asked to not get downvoted. As stated many are down vote trigger happy. He could have been in a very tight spot with his code. Now what? For him, nothing. As stated we're supposed to help each other not bring each other down.

Comment: "You are assuming he thinks the rules do not apply to him" -- there is no need to assume; they literally asked for special treatment.

Comment: Well he/she said in a Q on money stackexchange that (s)he will create software for it so I don't really believe their life is in danger. It seems to me that (s)he wishes to make money (which is fine), but without any hardwork(read resources about how Forex works), (s)he just asks 'give me API for this'. In a comment (s)he 'hopes' that Google will give better 'search results'. Even a tiny amount of efforts would've make them realize that the whole world is looking for something that tells about currency fluctuations 10 mins prior. Why should we help people trying to make money w/o any efforts?

Comment: maybe you should have read [the screenshot of the deleted question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345631/user-consciously-ignores-the-rules-of-asking-questions-on-so-what-to-do-about-i#comment457611_345631) then you'd realize there was no code the OP was stuck with, they were asking for an API.

Comment: also if you're saying that we shouldn't downvote/flag, regardless of content, just because the OP asked, that's a great idea! let me forward it to the spammers who can now update their bots to post *"please don't downvote and/or spam flag me until i get an answer"*

Comment: Of course context matters. If they are just expecting things handed to them then, of course, it should not be handed over to them so easily.

This is a perfect example of what I was talking about. I got 3 downvotes for what??? I just left a comment, I wasn't rude, I shared my view and I get downvoted.  Once again it just demotivates me more from using this site. I did absolutely NOTHING wrong.

Comment: @asmcriminal - Downvotes on meta.stackoverflow.com are used for agreement/disagreement; you should not assume that people are downvoting your answer here because you did anything wrong. Downvotes on the *main* Stack Overflow site are supposed to be for "this is a bad answer" rather than "I disagree with your opinion". But here on the Meta site, a downvote for "I disagree with your opinion" is *perfectly* appropriate, and is in fact the expected action. So do not feel discouraged that you were downvoted on this Meta question; it just means that people didn't agree with you, that's all.

Comment: *"I was working on a project … got stuck … asked for help … answer did not help … now the project is just sitting there"* — Do not blame a lack of progress on any project on SO! SO is not a substitute for doing your work. SO is not obliged to solve all your problems. If you are not making progress on your work, then ***you*** are not making progress on ***your*** work. SO is not responsible for that, ***you*** are.

Comment: If you don't pause and consider why you got down votes, then of course you will get demotivated... in fact that is actually the very purpose of down votes, to force posters to improve. There are rules of the main site for what we expect from questions, those who ignore the rules or don't take their time learning about them get down voted. Similarly, if you post on meta there are different rules you have to learn, namely that up/down votes are used to state agreement/disagreement. [Read this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259917/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work).

Comment: @deceze, I am not necessarily blaming SO.  I do agree with you in taking responsibility. In regards to the project discussed, I just do not know what to do at this point.

Comment: @Lundin, it takes me like 30mins to write a question. I do make sure that I followed the rules. I go through each point and make sure all points are met when asking a question. I still get down voted. How can I improve from this point? Some say, "you get downvoted because the person can not answer the question."  I have seen questions that are pretty bad who get high votes.

Comment: @asmcriminal It would only be meaningful to discuss that on case-by-case basis. Votes are of course quite subjective too, and you can always get up/down votes that you didn't deserve.

Comment: @asmcriminal I cannot see any of your downvoted questions, guess they got deleted. You mentioned them many times, have you asked here on meta "why" they are not meeting the SO guidelines?

Comment: You forgot to enclose this answer in <flamebait> </flamebait>